# Why is size of a collection greater than the number of products in that collection?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

In `toolbar.phtml` there is `$block->getCollection()->getSize()` which returns 67.

However if I do `count($block->getCollection()->getData())` the result is 12.

The layered navigation is also using the larger number.
The issue is on a page with a few bundle products on, so that may be a contributing factor.

Then when you go to the second page there are no results.

I am using the `Wyomind_Elasticsearch` and `Wyomind_Core` mode as the indexer for product.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that when you call `getData()` you are getting the keys to the objects `_data` property, but in a collection, the collection "items" live in `_items`, so to count the items, call `getItems()` and count that instead:

```
count($block->getCollection()->getItems())
```

Edit: if you chase down the `getSize()` function, you will see a call to `getSelectCountSql()` in `vendor/magento/framework/Data/Collection/AbstractDb.php` which will return the total number of results, not just the actual set of results in the current collection.

Comment: `count($_productCollection->getItems())` = 12 and 
`$_productCollection->getsize()` = 67